# Faster python alternative for discretize2d in R?

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted a python alternative to [discretize2d](https://rdrr.io/cran/entropy/src/R/discretize.R) in R. An alternative I found over stackoverflow was to use [pandas.crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) as so,

```
pandas.crosstab(pandas.cut(list1,bins=bin1,include_lowest=True),pandas.cut(list2,bins=bin2,include_lowest=True))
```

An example,

Say

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,2,4,5,1,13,5]
list2 = [15,2,5,7,3,5,2,5,7,9,3,0,3,6]

bin1 = np.linspace(start=min(list1),stop=max(list1),num=math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(list1)))+1)
bin2 = np.linspace(start=min(list2),stop=max(list2),num=math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(list2)))+1)
```

discretize2d would generate the following:

```
> discretize2d(list1, list2, numBins1 = sqrt(length(list1)), numBins2 = sqrt(length(list2)))
         
          [0,3.75] (3.75,7.5] (7.5,11.2] (11.2,15]
  [1,4]          3          4          1         1
  (4,7]          2          2          0         0
  (7,10]         0          0          0         0
  (10,13]        1          0          0         0
```

Similarly, the above mentioned pandas alternative generates the following

```
>>> pandas.crosstab(pandas.cut(a,bins=bin1,include_lowest=True), pandas.cut(b,bins=bin2,include_lowest=True), dropna=False)
col_0         (-0.001, 3.75]  (3.75, 7.5]  (7.5, 11.25]  (11.25, 15.0]
row_0
(0.999, 4.0]               3            4             1              1
(4.0, 7.0]                 2            2             0              0
(7.0, 10.0]                0            0             0              0
(10.0, 13.0]               1            0             0              0
```

I tried creating a faster alternative which I think works, but I'm not sure if it truly is the same as discretize2d,

```
>>> bin1[0]=min(bin1)-1
>>> bin2[0]=min(bin2)-1
>>> temp1 = np.digitize(a,bin1,right=True)
>>> temp2 = np.digitize(b,bin2,right=True)
>>> stack = np.column_stack((temp1,temp2))
>>> stack = stack.tolist()
>>> stack_set = set(tuple(x) for x in stack)
>>> table = np.zeros((max(temp1),max(temp2)))
>>> for k in stack_set:
...     table[k[0]-1][k[1]-1]=stack.count([k[0],k[1]])
...
>>> table
array([[3., 4., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

The above pandas alternative is quite slow when dealing with a large number of lists (say around 20 million). My alternative provided above is far more faster but I'm not sure if it behaves the same as discretize2d. Does my alternative behave the same as discretize2d ? Is there a faster python alternative to the above mentioned approaches ?

Comment: kindly add sample dataframe, with expected output. Kindly make the sample input dataframe reproducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`numpy.histogram2d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html):

Example:

```
list1 = np.random.normal(2, 1, 100)
list2 = np.random.normal(1, 1, 100)

bin1 = [0, 1, 3, 5]
bin2 = [0, 2, 3, 4, 6]

H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(list1, list2, bins=(bin1, bin2))

xlabels = [f"{l}-{r}" for l, r in zip(xedges, xedges[1:])]
ylabels = [f"{l}-{r}" for l, r in zip(yedges, yedges[1:])]

df = pd.DataFrame(H, index=xlabels, columns=ylabels)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      0-2   2-3  3-4  4-6
0-1  13.0   2.0  0.0  0.0
1-3  38.0  10.0  1.0  0.0
3-5  10.0   2.0  0.0  0.0

>>> xedges  # How to interpret
array([0, 1, 3, 5])  # [0, 1), [1, 3), [3, 5]  <- the last bin includes 5

>>> yedges  # How to interpret
array([0, 2, 3, 4, 6])  # [0, 2), [2, 3), [3, 4), [4, 6]  <- the last bin includes 6
```

**Update**: helper function

```
def labels(edges):
    labels = [f"[{l}, {r})" for l, r in zip(edges, edges[1:])]
    labels[-1] = labels[-1].replace(')', ']')
    return labels

df = pd.DataFrame(H, index=labels(xedges), columns=labels(yedges))
```

Output:

```
>>> df

        [0, 2)  [2, 3)  [3, 4)  [4, 6]
[0, 1)     9.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
[1, 3)    41.0    17.0     2.0     0.0
[3, 5]    12.0     4.0     0.0     0.0
```

**Update 2**

Modified version which includes the rightmost edge and the left first interval.

```
# With your new data: list1, list2, bin1, bin2
EPSILON = 1e-15  # hack to include the rightmost edge without changing bins

eps1 = [0] + [EPSILON] * (len(bin1) - 1)
eps2 = [0] + [EPSILON] * (len(bin2) - 1)

def labels(edges):
    labels = [f"({l}, {r}]" for l, r in zip(edges, edges[1:])]
    labels[0] = labels[0].replace('(', '[')
    return labels

H, _, _ = np.histogram2d(list1, list2, bins=(bin1+eps1, bin2+eps2))

df = pd.DataFrame(H, labels(bin1), labels(bin2), dtype=int)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
              [0.0, 3.75]  (3.75, 7.5]  (7.5, 11.25]  (11.25, 15.0]
[1.0, 4.0]              3            4             1              1
(4.0, 7.0]              2            2             0              0
(7.0, 10.0]             0            0             0              0
(10.0, 13.0]            1            0             0              0
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I updated the question with an example to make it more clear.

Comment: @maheshRao. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?